# Install program separate to OS

Tags: gratis, windows-7

OK, I *know* I had a program to do this before I reset my computer, but I have tried to remember and remember for the past month, and I can't.

I am looking (or, trying to remember) for a program that allows me to install a program in a 'virtual machine' basically. So, if I want to install an untrusted program, I can simply right click, open with PROGRAM, and it installs it into a virtual 'place' on my hard drive.

I need it to be **free** and **run on Windows 7 64 bit**.

Comment: Do you think of [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)?

Comment: @ComFreek YES! I do. I feel really stupid, but also really relieved now! Add it as an answer, and I'll accept :)

Comment: Be sure to save a [list of installed applications](http://superuser.com/questions/68611/get-list-of-installed-applications-from-windows-command-line) before the next reset :)

Comment: @ComFreek I asked that question on SR, didn't know there was a built in option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)

> Protection from rogue software, spyware and malware by isolating your
>   browser, PDF reader, and applications in a sandbox
>
> - Run programs in
>     a sandbox to prevent […] software […] from making permanent changes to
>     your machine
> - Protect yourself from a wide variety of attacks […]
> - Configure your own sandboxes to meet your specific
>     needs - install new software directly into a sandbox, run multiple
>     copies of the same on-line game, turn a single-instance application
>     into a multi-user application
>
> source: http://www.sandboxie.com/

Comment: +1 :) I might just wait and see if there are any alternatives from other people :)